# Creating a Modal using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, backbone.js, express

I am new to Backbone, and although I did some research, I could not find a solution that would work for me, in terms of creating a Modal.  I want to create a base Modal class, and then reuse/extend it and apply different templates, within my other view/classes.

Here is my Modal base class:

```
define([
  // Application.
  'app',
  'backbone',
  'plugins/jquery-ui.custom',
  'moment'
], function(App, Backbone) {
  // Create a new module.
  var Modal = App.module();

  Modal.View = Backbone.View.extend({
      className: 'ui-modal',

  render: function () {
      console.log('this.$el',this.$el,'this.template',this.template);
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        this.$el.delegate('.close', 'click', this.closeModal);
        this.error = this.$el.find('.error');
        return this;
      },

  closeModal: function (ev) {
        if (ev) ev.preventDefault();
        this.$el.unbind();
        this.$el.empty();
        this.$el.remove();
      },

  initialize: function () {
      console.log('initialize modal view', 'this.$el', this.$el);
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'closeModal');
        return Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.call(this);
    }
  });
```

I am trying to extend/utilize the Modal class here:

```
ProductDetails.Views.testView = Modal.View.extend({
    template: 'modals/ProductDetails/testView',
    render: function() {
      Modal.View.prototype.render.call(this);
      this.delegateEvents();
      return this;
    },
    initialize: function() {
      console.log('initialize testView','this.$el',this.$el);
      return Modal.View.prototype.initialize.call(this);
    }
  });
```

I am then trying to trigger the Modal here:

```
ProductDetails.Views.Description = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: 'partials/product/description',
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'serialize', 'warn', 'error', 'updateModel', 'testModalView');

      //instantiate the test modal
      this.testView = new ProductDetails.Views.testView();

      this.testView.$el = this.$el;
    },
    serialize: function(){
     //some stuff
    },
    events: {
      'click .testModalView_link': 'testModalView'
       //some other stuff
    },
    warn: function() {
      //some stuff
    },
    error: function(error){
      //some stuff
    },
    updateModel: function(e){
      //some stuff
    },
    testModalView: function(ev) {
      try {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $('.ui-modal').append(this.testView.render())
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message,e);
      }
    }
  });
```

I have doublechecked, but I may have made a mistake while attempting to simplify the code for inclusion within this question.  When I test my modal by clicking the link (with class .testModalView_link), I get the error: "TypeError: this.$el is undefined", and it points to the modal base class, to this line:

```
this.$el.html(this.template());
```

Can anyone help me make this work, or at least understand what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I gave it a quick go on jsfiddle and it seems to work fine. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/r8gk88mh/1/)

Comment: I am very confused then :) thanks for trying to help

Comment: It actually states that this.$el is undefined within testModal.render(), and then again when it gets to Modal.View.render().  However, I tested testModal.beforeRender(), and console.log outputs the wrong DIV for this.$el, so I'm guessing I am dealing with a scope problem.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I am having trouble creating a Fiddle for you.  The difference between your Fiddle, and how mine would be, is that mine would need to use require.js, and Lo-Dash, and would reference the modal template via its path and not via JQuery from within a preloaded template.

Comment: It looks like a scope problem, but it´s hard to tell what... When this.$el is undefined, what is `this`? Have you also had a look at the call stack? (Maybe that rings any bell as to what could go wrong). Another option would be start adding your differences to the code in the fiddle, and see when it breaks...

Comment: Thanks, yes, I actually was looking at 'this', and it seems to be wrong :) I am still looking into it.  I believe it could also be related to the way we are loading and compiling templates, and also our Backbone version.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  I am going to move on from this problem, I spent a lot of time debugging it, and even looking into alternative implementations; in the end I believe the issue is the way that we are loading and compiling templates, or the versions of the libraries/plugins we are using.  I have also noticed that similar issues occur when the DOM has not fully loaded, or elements are accessed before they are rendered; again, it could also be that with binding and callbacks, the scope isn't being handled properly.  If I do revisit the problem and discover the solid answer to it, I will be sure to provide an update.